# Time hierarchy theorem for search problems

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity

Wikipedia gives a [proof sketch](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_hierarchy_theorem) of the time hierarchy theorem by showing that appartenance to the following language:

$$H_f = \{([M], x) \ | \ M \ \text{accepts} \ x \ \text{in} \ f(|x|) \ \text{steps}\}$$

cannot be checked faster than by actually running $M$ on $x$ for $f(|x|)$ steps.

It makes me wonder what is known about the language:

$$S_f = \{ [M] \ | \ \exists{x} \ \text{s.t.} \\ M \ \text{accepts} \ x \ \text{in} \ f(|[M]|) \ \text{steps}, \\ \ |x| < f(|[M]|) \}$$

To me it looks like that for a given $M$ you have no other solution than to try all possible $x$ smaller than $f(|[M]|)$.
For $f$ polynomial, verifying a candidate solution $x$ is polynomial, but trying them all is exponential, which would prove $P \neq NP$ ...

So my reasoning is obviously wrong but I can't figure out why, and I also wonder more generally what is known about $S_f$ ?

Answer (score 1):

The main problem is that this proposal does not block a "clever" solution. So maybe the whole P versus NP problem can be solved in polynomial time with some clever trick. Maybe there's an NP-Complete [sparse language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mahaney%27s_theorem) out there somewhere to which all NP-complete problems can be reduced. Or maybe something that feels like a [natural proof](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_proof) that gets around the barriers. Or some beautiful number theory or algebraic trick.

More generally, maybe the structure of NP-complete problems is simpler than we currently understand. So a correct proof that P does not equal NP would have to block all these tricks, potentially infinitely many of them.

[This list](https://scottaaronson.blog/?p=458) might also be helpful if you haven't seen it already.

Comment: So are you saying that $S_f$ is indeed in $NP$ for $f$ polynomial, but that given an arbitrary Turing machine $M$ it is not proven yet that you have to try all bounded length $x$ to prove that $M$ accepts none of them?

Comment: No, that's another problem. You would need to show that it's in NP.

Comment: It is in $NP$ since if I give you a candidate solution $x$ you can verify it in polynomial time.